# Making Map so that anyone in ArcGIS Online organization can edit it?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I am using arcgis online and I have created a map with layers and I have made it public with everyone in the organization. The only issue is that though the map is visible and everyone in the organization can see it if they log online. The individuals cannot see or edit the map in the arcgis collector app when they go out into the field. How do I make it so that everyone can edit the map so that it's visible in the arcgis collector.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you publish your map it is found in the capabilities section, you need to have Feature Access and Mobile Data Access checked. This should allow for mobile editing.

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/mobile-data-services.htm

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/edit-features.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to have an editable feature service. So that means a feature layer with at least some variant of Add/Update/Delete. Also you need to share your maps to groups and have the other users who will access that map and service added to the same group. The app does not grab all content across the org, it needs to be set to specific groups.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. If you're using a feature service layer, then you need to go into the settings for the feature services, which is one of the tabs on the page of the layer.

The information in the following link was helpful for me: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-layers.htm